# How to transfer a file in an "indirect" ssh connection?

Tags: linux, networking, ssh, scp

I have to access my server in such way: localhost -> remote1 -> remote2 (my server)

```
[xxxx@localhost] $ ssh yyyy@remote1
[yyyy@remote1]   $ ssh zzzz@remote2
[zzzz@remote2]   $ echo "now I logined into my server..."
```

I know how to transfer files with scp. however I have no read or write permissions on remote1. How can I transfer a file to remote2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
ssh -L localhost:8022:remote2:22 remote1
```

Now, you can use `localhost` port `8022` to contact `22` of `remote2` via `remote1`. This session session should be active whenever you need to transfer. Use

```
scp -P 8022 /path/locale/file 127.0.0.1:/path/on/remote2
```

This is commonly called as `SSH Tunneling`. You can search and get to know lot about it.

Answer (score 2):

Another alternative could be to use a Proxy command:

```
scp -o ProxyCommand='ssh yyy@remote1 netcat %h %p 2> /dev/null' zzz@remote2:fromfile tofile
```

if `remote1` has `netcat` installed. Other viable options could be `nc` or `socat` (the latter has a different syntax).